# Can I use ssh in "forwarding mode" as a workaround missing Telnet in High Sierra?

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

If you haven't noticed, telnet is gone from MacOS high Sierra.

I'm experimenting with ways to use built in MacOS utilities to function as a basic TCP-based VT100 emulator... an ASCII console that's dumb as bricks.

I have tried SSH in "forwarding mode", but unsure of the syntax of source and remote port/socket

> ssh -L 192.168.1.162:30000

SSH without encryption

> nothing yet, but experimenting with cipher=null and other settings...

**Question**

Is there any way to make SSH act like Telnet?  In port forwarding or other modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using built in utilities the answer would be `nc`. `nc` is easy to use for this, a simple `nc <hostname> 23` does the job. Obviously, if your telnet host is using a non-standard port then replace `23` with the port number. `<hostname>` can be either the name or IP address.

`nc` is the BSD version of the Gnu/Linux `netcat` utility. If you want the Gnu version it is available via homebrew, `brew install netcat`. If you're going to that much trouble you may as well install `telnet` from Sierra on your High Sierra Mac via homebrew, `brew install telnet`. Note that you should never run `brew` via `sudo`.